# How can I split a methods functionality using an enum as condition?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have the following code:

```
enum Example {

    ex1,ex2

}

public void method(Example exType) {

    if(exType.equals(ex1)) {
        //do similar stuff
        method2(exType)
    } else if(exType.equals(ex2)) {
        //do similar stuff
        method2(exType)
    } else {
        //throw exception
    }

}

public void method2(Example exType) {

    if(exType.equal(ex1)) {
        //do similar stuff
    } else if(exType.equals(ex2)) {
        //do similar stuff
    } else {
        //throw exception
    }
}
```

The problem is the method calls other methods that behave in the same way. So it doesn't look very good as an implementation. How can i split this behavior?

Edit:
Using enum is not mandatory. Similar means they call same-named method and update same-named fields, one just does less than the other. Inside the `//Do similar stuff` it calls another method with the enum as a parameter and that method has the same structure of code.

Edit 2: 
Added some more code. This just doesn't seem like the right approach

Comment: Is it mandatory to use Enum?

Comment: What is similar stuff? Is it calling a same-named method or updating a same-named  field

Comment: It is not mandatory to use an enum. It is calling same-named method and updating same-named fields, but one does less than the other.

Comment: @D.Tomov: Thanks for the edit. But I don't see what is wrong with your code as it is (although I would use a `switch`). Please explain why you think this doesn't look like a good implementation and what you mean by splitting this behavior. What behavior?

Comment: @D.Tomov: Please consider https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is your "do similar stuff", inside there something must run 2 times? If the 2nd method would overload the first "do similar stuff", it is advisable you combine into one method with if-else or switch to check the conditions.

Comment: @D.Tomov I have added an interface and a common method in case these are useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's worth remembering that Enum values are objects rather than `int` values like they are in other languages. This allows you to use polymorphism with them removing the need for switch statements in many cases.

```
interface IExample {
   // you can use interfaces if you need them
   void method1();
}

enum Example implements IExample {
    ex1 {
        public void method1() {
            // do stuff
            method2();
        }
        public void method2() {
            // do other stuff
        }
    },
    ex2 {
        public void method1() {
            // do stuff
            method2();
        }
        public void method2() {
            // do other stuff
            method3(); // not all methods need to be different.
        }
    };

    public abstract void method1(); // only needed if you don't use an interface
    public abstract void method2(); // does it need to be public as well?
    public void method3() { /* added as an example */ }
}
```

There is no need to throw an exception as your code won't compile if you forget to provide an implementation for a new `enum` value.

The `IExample` might be an existing interface or it might be needed for extention. e.g.

```
class Example2 implements IExample {
   int x;
   public Example2(int x) { this.x = x; }
   public void method1() {
       // uses x
   }
}
```

Now you can write

```
IExample e = Example.ex1; // fixed value

IExample e2 = new Example2(5); // extendable at runtime.
```

---

**Why would you do this?**

There is an example I use.

[SystemTimeProvider](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Core/blob/master/src/main/java/net/openhft/chronicle/core/time/SystemTimeProvider.java) - a singleton implemented as an `enum`

[SetTimeProvider](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Core/blob/master/src/main/java/net/openhft/chronicle/core/time/SetTimeProvider.java) a class where each instance can have a different fixed time for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `switch` instead. Also with `Enums` you can use `==`, but you don't need that when using a `switch`. What about this!

```
enum Example {

    ex1,ex2

}

public void method(Example exType) {

    switch (exType) {
         case ex1:
             // do 1
             break;
         case ex2:
             // do 2
             break;
         default:
             //throw exception
    }

}
```

Comment: Because the /do stuff calls another method that has to have the same logic. I will have to use switch again in it. This doesn't help sorry.

Comment: In that case, please re-explain your problem. It is not clear what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

First of all its better to use `switch case` because in case in future there are more no of enums and then more no of if conditions then code becomes less readable.

One of the approach could be

```
enum Example {
  ex1,ex2
}

public void method(Example exType) {

    switch (exType) {
       case ex1:
         methodEx1(); 
         break;
       case ex2:
         methodEx1();  
         break;
       default:
         //throw exception
   }
 }
```

Function methodEx1();  and  methodEx2(); add all the codes corresponds to enum in a single function instead of writing of multiple function for same enum.